# When to use das/die/der and when ein/eine?

Tags: grammatical-case, article, definite-article

I'm just starting with German and got a bit lost when one should use der/die/das and when ein/eine. I suppose it should be something like "a" or "the" in English depending if we're talking about something concrete or something in general.

P.S.: consider nominative only.

Comment: You gave the answer yourself. Is there a special case why do you think your assumption is incorrect? Then put it into your question.

Comment: @John, that was just a feeling of how it should be (which apparently was correct), no specific cases so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, most of the time you should use "der/die/das" when you would use "the", "ein/eine" when you would use "a/an", and none when you would use none in English. Giving exact rules is nearly impossible (try it for "the" and "a").

Generally if you talk about something which was already mentioned, or which is common knowledge, you should use "der/die/das". If you introduce new information, you should use "ein/eine". If you are talking about unique, singular things like "Frankreich", you don't use any article at all (but strange enough it is still "das Universum/Weltall"). Sometimes you leave out the article as well when you talk about general concepts like "Freiheit".

Getting a feeling for the correct use of articles is really hard for people who speak non-European languages. Speaking fluent, natural English will be very helpful for chosing the right German article.

**[Edit]**

As you see in the comments, the situation isn't even clear for countries, so as a little bonus here a link to a list of countries with article:
http://deutschlernen-blog.de/blog/2007/07/11/grammatik-liste-der-laendernamen-die-mit-artikel-gebraucht-werden/

Of course, if you have an official country name including something like "Republik" or "Königreich", you need an article, too. E.g. "die Bundesrepublik Deutschland" :-)

Comment: a better *strange counter evidence* for *Frankreich* would be *die Schweiz*, *die USA*, *der Irak* ... ;p

Comment: @Em1, isn't it *den USA*? (sorry for off-topic)

Comment: @den-javamaniac Not for nominative.

Comment: @den-javamaniac We use the abbreviation USA as well, but it's spelled out as "die Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika", so we use the plural article.

Comment: _Der Rhein_, _die Charité_ and _das Weserstadion_ are also unique, singular things. I'm not sure if this concept helps.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt It's your chance to give a better answer...

Comment: @Landei: Yes, I would - if I only could `:-)`

Comment: Die Türkei (oder andere Länder auf -ei), der Tschad, die Ukraine, ...

Comment: I propose we use "das Frankreich" from now on, to make it simpler ;-)

Comment: *Generally if you talk about something whoch [sic] was already mentioned, or which is common knowledge, you should use "der/die/das"*. I think introducing the correct grammatical terminology for der/die/das (definite article) would be of value to avoid ambiguity with relative pronouns, which can take the same forms.